# When not to use memcache

Tags: php, memcached

Currently we are having a site which do a lot of api calls from our parent site for user details and other data. We are planning to cache all the details on our side. I am planning to use memcache for this. as this is a live site and so we are expecting heavier traffic in coming days(not that like FB but again my server is also not like them ;) ) so I need your opinion what issues we can face if we are going for memcache and cross opinions of yours why shouldn't we go for it. Any other alternative will also help.

Comment: see the disadvantages http://benrobb.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/memcached.pdf

Answer (score 16, accepted):

https://github.com/steveyen/community-site/blob/master/db_doc/main/WhyNotMemcached.wiki

Memcached is terrific! But not for every situation...

- You have objects larger than 1MB.

  - Memcached is not for large media and streaming huge blobs.
  - Consider other solutions like: http://www.danga.com/mogilefs
- You have keys larger than 250 chars.

  - If so, perhaps you're doing something wrong?
  - And, see this mailing list conversation on [key size](http://lists.danga.com/pipermail/memcached/2007-January/003388.html) for suggestions.
- Your hosting provider won't let you run memcached.

  - If you're on a low-end virtual private server (a slice of a machine), virtualization tech like vmware or xen might not be a great place to run memcached. Memcached really wants to take over and control a hunk of memory -- if that memory gets swapped out by the OS or hypervisor, performance goes away. Using virtualization, though, just to ease deployment across dedicated boxes is fine.
- You're running in an insecure environment.

  - Remember, anyone can just telnet to any memcached server. If you're on a shared system, watch out!
- You want persistence. Or, a database.

  - If you really just wish that memcached had a SQL interface, then you probably need to rethink your understanding of caching and memcached.

Comment: You're missing a link to the mailing list for key sizes.

Comment: @Dana the Sane, thank you, feel free to edit my answer. First link points to full version.

Answer (score 2):

You should implement a generic caching layer for the API calls first. Within the domain of the caching layer you can then change the strategy which backend you want to use. If you then see that memcache is not fitting you can actually switch (and/or testwise monitor how it works compared with other backends).

Even better, you can first code this build upon the filesystem quite easily (which has multiple backends, too) without the hurdle to rely on another daemon, so already get started with caching - probably file system is already enough for your caching needs?

Comment: We tried implementing memcache for all the Db queries and api responses . Our server response time reduced . But again we are trying to store all the users details in memcache as their details are shown at different point to different users and we dont have any users details. So how will memcache perform after we will add enough keys and values in it.

Comment: No Idea, I don't know your data nor your system nor can I inspect any of both. In the end you need to find out for your system where the limits are that trigger the bottle neck.

Answer (score 2):

Memcache is fast, but it also can use a lot of memory if you want to get the most out of it. Whenever you hit the disk for I/O, you're increasing the latency of your application. Pull items that are frequently accessed and put them on memcache. For my large scale deployments, we cache sessions there because DB is slow as well as filesystem session storage.

A recommendation to add to your stack is APC. It caches PHP files and lessens the overall memory usage per page.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative: Redis

Memcached is, obviously, limited by your available memory and will start to jettison data when memory thresholds are reached. You may want to look [redis](http://redis.io/) which is as fast (faster in some benchmarks) as memcached but allows the use of both volatile and non-volatile keys, more complex data structures, and the option of using virtual memory to put Least Recently Used (LRU) key values to disk.

Comment: Yeah we looked into it but we didn't find it attractive enough to fight against general practice :)

Comment: It shouldn't be any harder to develop a redis-backed caching solution than a memcache solution, unless you are planning on using something pre-built.